# select multiple form

Tags: html, css

how can  i make a  form where you dont need to hold down control key to select multiple options ?

i want to make it so that when you just click on any of the options, they will be highlighted.

Comment: What kind of input element are we talking about? Checkboxes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... would input check boxes be up to it or do you not want check boxes. I think normal UI paradigm would be to have the checkbox in this situation, otherwise how would you deselect? There's a lot to be said for not inventing your own UI conventions in terms of usability.

Comment: No, I think it's a select (`<SELECT NAME="option_name" MULTIPLE>`) thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of checkboxes instead of using a list box:
http://www.siteexperts.com/tips/html/ts16/page1.asp

This List Box containing checkboxes will also work:

**JavaScript ListBox Control**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/List_Box.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an option in regular html. I'd suggest, though, that in many cases it might be easier to use checkboxes to allow for multiple items in the same list to be selected. To my mind it's also easier from a UI point of view.

Perhaps Javascript has an option, though? I wouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could even use [dragable checkboxes](http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/clickndrag_checkboxes.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using JavaScript if you want to keep the ListBox rather than use CheckBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jquery for any kind of custom ui or form elements. There are tons of form plugins for jquery. Check it :)

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/20